# PDF redirected to php file using htaccess—removed but still persists W3 total cache

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, w3-total-cache

A previous developer created an entry into the htaccess of a worpress site in a few areas.

1. In the root directory
2. In the directory that contains wp-content etc.

That rule is as follows:

```
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f    
# RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$ download-protect.php?file=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
# disable directory browsing in WordPress
```

As you can see they are both commented out, but the PDF is still redirected. So a few questions:

Which directory .htaccess would this be best applied to?

Why would PDF's still be redirected if this is commented out? No other trace of that rule anywhere else.

Could it be W3 total cache?

Some context is I need to fix this as it's going to http as opposed to https and the file itself basically says if logged in continue to PDF if not show "must be logged in" message.

https://bvfoods.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/90029-BV-WG-Cinnamon-Crumble-2.9-oz.pdf

Redirects to

http://bvfoods.com/new/download-protect.php?thisFile=2018/06/90029-BV-WG-Cinnamon-Crumble-2.9-oz.pdf

which if logged in redirects back to the original PDF and if not it displays the must be logged in screen.

Comment: Could you please post samples of from which url to which url(in backend) you want to redirect? Please add this in question for better understanding of question.

Comment: Sure.. Updating now.

Comment: I am sorry I am not getting a thought as of now on your issue, though I tried my best. People usually don't think that way if somebody deletes answer, they understand about this one, so please don't think no one will jump on this one, because I deleted the answer, keeping not done answer may confuse users browsing in future, if I get more thoughts on this one I will edit and un-delete it, cheers.